compute eigenvectors of an $n\times n$ linear transform knowing the eigenvectors of an $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ linear transform on a projected subspace
Supposed I'm trying to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a square $n\times n$ matrix $A_{n}$.  Further suppose that I've applied some algorithm and identified one eigenvalue and eigenvector pair $(\lambda_n, v_n)$.   My question is the following: is there a transform, (call it $T: \mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{C}^{n-1}$ such that $T(v_n) = 0$), which I can use to convert $A_{n}$ to $A_{n-1}$, an $(n-1)\times(n-1)$?   After computing $A_{n-1}$, imagine that I (somehow) find its $n-1$ eigenvectors.  Can I then promote/unproject them back to eigenvalues of $A_n$?
What I don't see is once we have the eigenvectors of $A_{n-1}$, each an element in $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$, how can we un-project them back into $\mathbb{C}^n$.  The projection, $T$, after all, is not invertable.
